# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get' (django view)

Tags: python, django

This is communication between ajax operation and django view.

There is a form, and if I click submit button of the form, the Ajax code excuted.

But it consistently makes error, written below. I can't figure out the reason of it. I suppose this is related to how form is conveyed to a view, but I don't know how to fix it.

```
Internal Server Error: /makeevent
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/workspace/CalendarProject/cencal/views.py", line 42, in makeevent
    if form.is_valid():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 185, in is_valid
    return self.is_bound and not self.errors
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 180, in errors
    self.full_clean()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 381, in full_clean
    self._clean_fields()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 393, in _clean_fields
    value = field.widget.value_from_datadict(self.data, self.files, self.add_prefix(name))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/forms/widgets.py", line 258, in value_from_datadict
    return data.get(name)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Javascript code:

```
function makeEvent(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            var year = event.target.childNodes[3].children[0].value.slice(0,4);
            var month = event.target.childNodes[3].children[0].value.slice(5,7);
            var day = event.target.childNodes[3].children[0].value.slice(8,10);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "{% url 'makeevent' %}",
                data: {'form': $("#makeEventForm").serialize(), 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'},
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(response){
                    console.log(response);
                    refreshCalendarAjax(year, month);
                    listevent(year, month, day);
                    document.getElementById("sidebar").insertAdjacentHTML( 'afterbegin', "Create new event successful." );
                },
                error: function(request,status,error){
                    if (status == 599) {
                        $("#sidebar").html = error;
                    } else {
                       console.log(error); 
                    }
                },
            });
        }
```

Django view code:

```
def makeevent(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = EventForm(request.POST['form'])
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponse("Successful", status=200)
        else:
            return HttpResponse(form.errors, status=599)
    else:
        print("NOT POST");
```

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Try returning `405` error instead of printing a string.

Comment: @Jarvis You mean, when it is valid?

Comment: Something wrong with your form data. try to print it and see if it's in the expected form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Jsonify the response string.
Example: 
HttpResponse({
 "Status": "Successful"
})